# Hibernate + Spring - xml mapping not found

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm

I have simple application with following folder structure:

- ProjFolder
- |-----src
- |----------packagename
- |---------------{sourcefiles}
- |----------META-INF
- |---------------{beans.xml}
- |---------------{hibernate.cfg.xml}
- |---------------{EntityMapping.hbm.xml}

here is the part of beans.xml Spring config file:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:./META-INF/jdbc.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:./META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
<list>
      <value>classpath:./META-INF/EntityMapping.hbm.xml</value>
</list>
 </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

when i start my unit tests i getting following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'wrapperClass' defined in class path resource
>   [META-INF/beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'wrapperClassField'
>   while setting constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'xmlBooksource' defined in class path resource
>   [META-INF/beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [META-INF/beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [classpath:/META-INF/EntityMapping.hbm.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

The same exception is thrown when i type

```
<property name="mappingResources">
<list>
      <value>EntityMapping.hbm.xml</value>
</list>
 </property>
```

Why spring cant find this file and how i must fill its location to make this code work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As i wrote in the beginning of question - yes. META-INF is a subfolder of src, so i can assume that including it into sourcepath wont solve the problem

Comment: Right.  Have you tried removing the `classpath:` prefix?  In looking at the code, that setter expects a classpath resource already.  The string then gets passed to `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried removing the `classpath:` prefix? In looking at the Hibernate code, the [`mappingResources`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setMappingResources%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) setter expects passes the strings to [`new ClassPathResource(String)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html#ClassPathResource%28java.lang.String%29).  This expects classpath resources already.  The string then gets passed to [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).  None of this code would strip the "classpath:" prefix from the front of the resource string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the error message is consistent with the beans.xml content you posted.
In the error you have

```
[classpath:/META-INF/EntityMapping.hbm.xml]
```

which isn't the same as

```
 classpath:./META-INF/EntityMapping.hbm.xml
```

Notice the missing "." at the beginning in the error.

The second beans.xml configuration, should probably produce a different error message with:

```
[classpath:EntityMapping.hbm.xml]
```

This would be searching for the file in the root of your compiled application (jar, war, exploded, what have you).

Comment: Leading dot in path is just ommitted in error message. I'v tried once again right now.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully configure Hibernate 4 with Spring 3.1. My applicationContext.xml file is inside web-inf folder and has the following hibernate cofiguration:

```
<!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
 <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
  <!--  
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>iltaf.models.Levels</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  -->

    <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath:iltaf/models/*.hbm.xml" />


    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>

  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

 <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and I have separate hibernate.cfg.xml file inside my src folder. I am using Eclipse Juno Java EE version.